# calculate mean values of weather data for each hour and day of the year based on historical data

Tags: r, aggregate, average

I need to calculate average values of meteorological data for each day and hour of the year  based on hourly historic data of 2015 - 2023 in r programming. The average hourly values will be used to create a series for 2024 that will represent "normal weather". Does anyone have any idea on how I could do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without getting a glimpse of the data it's almost impossible to give any hints other than `aggregate(hours ~ year + day, df, mean)`. Maybe you can post some data with `dput(head(data, 20))`?

Comment: You simply `group_by` hour and day of the year, then `summarize` the mean temperature. We can't show you the exact code to do that, because we don't know the names or  structure of any of your variables. Concrete solutions with code require concrete questions with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to calculate daily means for some hourly weather data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(nycflights13) # Contains weather data set

weather %>% 
  group_by(origin, year, month, day) %>% 
  summarise(temp = mean(temp), humid = mean(humid))
```

To answer your question better, we need an example of your data. It's also unclear what you mean by "create a series for 2024" based on the 2015-2023 data.

Comment: I adjusted this to my data and it worked perfectly, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you have to deal with (complicated) time series also the R-package `timetk` might be interesting for you.
It has two nice functions `summarize_by_date` and `summarize_by_time` that may be of interest for you. URL: https://business-science.github.io/timetk/